# SwiftUI: Error "Unable to infer complex closure return type" seems to show up arbitrarily

Tags: swiftui

I am very new to programming. Sorry if the format isn't right.

I had the code below working just fine before I added a simple textview in one of the Vstacks. Then the error showed up next to the Form. But even if I delete what I added, the error wouldn't go away. Then I tried to delete the Form. It moved to the navigationview. I am completely stumped.

I searched in Stackoverflow, swift.org, medium. The results are not really related to VStack. So I don't know how to add return type to a Form. I am sure I did something wrong there but just couldn't figure it out.

Huge thanks in advance!

FYI This is from HackingWithSwift Project 4 BetterRest

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView () {
            Form {
                VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
                    Text("When do you want to wake up?")
                        .font(.headline)

                    DatePicker("Plase enter a time", selection: $wakeUp, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                        .labelsHidden()
                        .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())
                }

                VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
                    Text("Desired amount of sleep")
                        .font(.headline)

                    Stepper(value: $sleepAmount, in: 4...12, step: 0.25) {
                        Text("\(sleepAmount, specifier: "%g") hours")
                    }
                }

                VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
                    Text("Daily coffee intake")
                    .font(.headline)

                    Stepper(value: $coffeeAmount, in: 1...20) {
                        if coffeeAmount == 1 {
                            Text("1 cup")
                        } else {
                            Text("\(coffeeAmount) cups")
                        }
                    }
                }
                VStack{
                    Button(action: calculateBedtime) {
                        Text("Calculate")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("BetterRest")
            .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert){
                Alert(title: Text(alertTitle), message: Text(alertMessage), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I answered your question before, showing the code is working , hence to look elsewhere for the possible cause of your problem, but someone deleted it

Comment: I did have a chance to glance your reply before it was deleted. Unfortunately I had to start my day job before actually trying it out.  But still, a million thanks for answering my question. I am so glad you mentioned my code looks ok cuz I have checked again and again and couldn't spot anything. 

BTW, do you know why your answer was deleted? I really wish I could try it out :(

Comment: I have no idea why my answer was deleted, it seems to be useful to know that the code can work. It's very rude and not having the courage of providing an explanation shows that person's true character.

Comment: Still a huge thanks to you :)

I am also asking this question on reddit. Will see how it goes.

Comment: hi workingdog, FYI, someone on reddit solved the error by removing the returning code in calculateBedtim(). The code now works fine now.   ^^

Comment: glad you found a solution. Note that here on SO we didn't have the code you used for calculateBedtim().